# Can SpeechRecognizer support other languages?

Tags: android, speech-recognition

like what the title states, is it possible for SpeechRecognizer to recognize other languages? If i want it to recognize mandarin instead of english, how would i set that up? Thanks.

Comment: In code or just in general?

Comment: if you could show me in code, it'd be great!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not know if the Google speech recognizer engine support Mandarin, but if it is then you can get it to recognize Mandarin by using the EXTRA_LANGUAGE

```
Intent intent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE, "zh-cmn");
```

Document link http://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/RecognizerIntent.html#EXTRA_LANGUAGE